# How to set background animation only above background image portion?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have provided background animation example. In the snippet there is  star animation above image. My problem is  animation overlaps to remaining part of the page. I want that animation only above image. I don't want that animation above that red background portion below image.

[Animation example](https://jsfiddle.net/6h3tagsv/)

```
6h3tagsv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your stars are `position: absolute` and your animation changes their position to be outside the `.visual-banner` one of the solutions is to add `overflow: hidden` to `.visual-banner`.

Comment: Thanks bro  it helped

Answer (score 2):

Adding `overflow:hidden` to `.visual-banner` will solve this.

```
.visual-banner {
   /* other props */
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6h3tagsv/2/)